# Cocoa get default paper size?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing, size

How to get the default paper size?

I am making an app, which will create a document based on your location. I want the document to be be generated silently, without user having to interact. For example, if user lives in US, I want to know that the paper size is US Letter. If the user is from Europe, I want to know if it is A4.

So how do I get the default paper size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have looked at Apple's documentation regarding printing?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPrintInfo

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/Reference/reference.html

Otherwise, can you be more precise where you need the page format or for what purposes?

Comment: NSPrintInfo * printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
NSLog(@"Paper size = %@", [printInfo localizedPaperName]);

That's what I was looking for :)